# How to determine what path of an app alias is used when double clicking on the alias

Tags: swift, macos, filesystems, alias

*-- macos file system with application aliases --*

In some type of project folders I want to have an `alias` to an macos application that will do some work in that project folder.

I would want to write that application in swift. The create an `alias` in the project folder. That app should determine where the `path` of the `alias` is when double clicked. That way I can work directly in the right folder and do some actions.

I am searching for two days now and can't find anything, maybe it is dead simple, but cant figure it out. Any documentation about this or samples, in Swift, AppleScript, Automator or whatever suggestion available, please let me know.

I guess, in an executable shell script I could do something like

```
    "$(dirname "$0")"
```

and passing this through to an open command to open the original app. But it is just a guess and I would rather like to create an alias instead of a kickstarter helper script.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Will that macOS application run as part of an Xcode target? (Please pay attention to capitalization: **S**wift, mac**OS**, **A**pple**S**cript, ....)

Comment: Hi, No, it will run in-depended. It will only get activated when I double click on that alias. So far as I know is macos lowercase.

Comment: No it's [macOS](https://www.apple.com/lae/macos/mojave/). You could have checked that in about the same time as writing you think it's not :-)

Comment: You forgot to give the solution about my problem. ;)

Comment: Is "That app" your app? Do you want to know which alias was used to launch your app? The project folder isn't a Xcode project folder?

Comment: Indeed, the app is mine, right now developing. Yes, would like to know which alias was used to launch with that app. The folder isn't a XCode project folder.

Comment: Do you have an answer about this?